# Using awk to print columns containing multiple patterns

Tags: text-processing, awk

I need to use `awk` to print the columns containing multiple patterns. I need to print column #2 as well as all the columns containing "config" and "service" respectively.

File content:

```
    build 345 java groovy /test:fail.txt /config:launcher.mxres /nickname:prod /service:session 
    auto 4986 java -xmx512 -d64 /test:pass.txt /nickname:deal /service:engine /config:launcher5.mxres
    build 912 binary.exe -f -t /test:code.txt /config:launcher_binary.mxres /service:scanner /nickname:input
```

Output:

```
    345 /config:launcher.mxres /service:session
    4986 /config:launcher5.mxres /service:engine
    912 /config:launcher_binary.mxres /service:scanner
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following `awk` script will go through the fields (columns) of each line and look for the `/config:` and `/service:` fields. When found, the full content of these fields are stored in variables.

Once the fields have been processed, the script outputs the data in the second field together with the found fields from the loop. The process then continues with the next line of input.

```
{
    config = service = "";

    for (i = 3; i <= NF; ++i) {
        if ($i ~ "^/config:") {
            config = $i;
        } else if ($i ~ "^/service:") {
            service = $i;
        }
    }

    print $2, config, service;
}
```

This script has been tested and works with `gawk` (GNU `awk`), `mawk` (Mike's `awk`) and `nawk` (BSD `awk`).

Running this on the data that you supplied:

```
$ awk -f script.awk data
345 /config:launcher.mxres /service:session
4986 /config:launcher5.mxres /service:engine
912 /config:launcher_binary.mxres /service:scanner
```

If you want tab-delimited output, add `BEGIN { OFS = "\t" }` at the top of the script.

... or you could pass the output of the original script through `column -t` (will insert multiple spaces if needed to align columns):

```
$ awk -f script.awk data | column -t
345   /config:launcher.mxres         /service:session
4986  /config:launcher5.mxres        /service:engine
912   /config:launcher_binary.mxres  /service:scanner
```

As a one-liner:

```
$ awk '{ config = service = ""; for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { if ($i ~ "^/config:") { config = $i } else if ($i ~ "^/service:") { service = $i } } print $2, config, service }' data | column -t
```

Comment: I need the solution in one command line and not a script please

Comment: @ekassis Sorted.

Comment: @kusalananda, you're too good to him

Comment: @J.Chomel I know. I'm a nice guy. It's a problem I have.

Comment: thank you @Kusalananda it works fine but with the / instead of " and I removed the column -t since I don't have it.
       `$ awk '{ config = service = ""; for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i) { if ($i ~ /^\/config:/) { config = $i } else if ($i ~ /^\/service:/) { service = $i } } print $2, config, service }' data `